# getting both time and date from calendar control

Tags: asp.net

hi i am using calender control in asp.net. in this i want to get both  current time and  current date.  how can i do this? i am using the language c#. help me

Answer (score 4):

Yes we can with an amendment..
Example

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
dt=dt.Add(ts);
txtreffDt.Text = dt.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The ASP.Net Calendar is just that - a calendar. Calendars only deal with dates. You'll need a third party `DateTimePicker` control or similar.